# i am trying to pass outlook funcaptcha using Twocaptcha but not working

Tags: python, captcha, 2captcha

I am trying to bypass funcaptcha throug twocaptcha using python. But could not

here is my code also

```
solver = CaptchaSolver(CaptchaSolvingService.TWOCAPTCHA, api_key='')
solver.get_balance()
solver = solver.solve_funcaptcha('B7D8911C-5CC8-A9A3-35B0-554ACEE604DA','https://signup.live.com/signup')
time.sleep(90)
```

I am trying to bypass funcaptcha throug twocaptcha using python. But could not

here is my code also

```
solver = CaptchaSolver(CaptchaSolvingService.TWOCAPTCHA, api_key='')
solver.get_balance()
solver = solver.solve_funcaptcha('B7D8911C-5CC8-A9A3-35B0-554ACEE604DA','https://signup.live.com/signup')
time.sleep(90)
```

Comment: It may be they can't solve it at all or blocked solving on some websites, just use another service.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the grid method to solve the captcha, the normal method of implementation does not work for outlook, nor has it for the past couple years.

Comment: What is the grid method?